# Practical meaning of Bayesian estimation of the distribution parameter

Tags: statistics, self-learning

I'm confused in the textbook's (A.Borovkov "Mathematical statistics") condition : "the Bayesian estimation of the distribution parameter the best in the sense of the root-mean-square approach".
There is a definition

"Estimation $\theta^*_{Q}$ defined by formula
$$
q(t/x) = \frac{f_t(x)q(t)}{f(x)}, \text{ } f(x)=\int f_t(x)q(t)\lambda(dt)
$$
$$
 \theta^*_{Q} = E(\theta|X) = \int tq(t/X)\lambda(dt)
$$
called the Bayesian estimation of the parameter $\theta$ corresponding to the a priori distribution $Q$ with density equal to $q(t)$."

Note that
$$
E(\theta^*-\theta)^2 = EE((\theta^*-\theta)|\theta) = EE_{\theta}(\theta^*-\theta)^2 = \int E_{t}(\theta^*-t)^2q(t)\lambda(dt)
$$
takes the smallest possible value. So then the author says that the Bayesian estimation minimizes the average value of $E_t(\theta^*-\theta)^2$. In other words "the Bayesian estimation of the distribution parameter the best in the sense of the root-mean-square approach".

My question is why the following sentence is true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The passage says that by applying the Bayesian estimation approach, the estimator minimizes the average squared difference between the estimated and true parameter values of the distribution. This is a common measure for evaluating the quality of an estimator in statistics.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi, the question is why the Bayesian estimation approach minimizes the average squared difference between the estimated and true parameter values of distribution.

Comment: The challenge should be to prove that the derivative of the MSE with respect to $\theta^*$ is zero at the point $\theta^*_{Q}$.

Comment: I can't follow that notation at the top of your question but, if you have or can get  ferguson's, "statistical decision theory", a nice proof that bayesian estimators minimize squared loss should be in there, assuming my memory is still mostly there.

Comment: This looks like a good document. I think the proof is there in 1.3. https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture14.pdf